# TableView doesnt stretch to full screen in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Im following a course on Udemy and the guy puts a new Table View on the storyboard and stretches it to full screen. But when I try it myself it doesnt allow me to stretch to the top 100%. It leaves the area for battery and time area. Im using Swift 4.2 You can see in the screenshot:

```
http://prntscr.com/n1xln3
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well its normal, guess like a clock and battery its a normal component, if you just put the constraints with top margin 0, the Xcode put te table with 0px off space for this component, a tip you can try is this:
[image]

I change the main view to red to you see more easily, when a open the constraints now, a top constraints is that:

[image]

Because now is referring to the top of the view don't a clock and battery view

Comment: Where is that option to Add New Constraints?

Comment: Select the component and clear all constraints, so you add the news